# Use execve with argv (Piping)

Tags: c, multiprocessing, pipe, exec, dup2

I got the piping of several commands working. Now Id like to execute this with received arguments (`*argv[]`) and not hard coded like here.

Ived tried using the rest of the execve family but no progress.
Ive been thinking to put everything (argv) in an array of pointers and adding NULL at the end of where each pointer points, then iterate through it.

Passed argument ( `,` included): `echo "test" , wc , cowsay`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *echo[] = {"echo", "test", NULL};
    char *rev[] = {"rev", NULL};
    char *wc[] = {"wc", NULL};
    char **cmd[] = {echo, wc, rev, NULL};

    loop_pipe(cmd);
    return (0);
}

void loop_pipe(char ***cmd) {
    int p[2];
    pid_t pid;
    int fd_in = 0;

    while (*cmd != NULL) {
        pipe(p);
        if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            dup2(fd_in, 0); //change the input according to the old one
            if (*(cmd + 1) != NULL)
                dup2(p[1], 1);
            close(p[0]);
            execvp((*cmd)[0], *cmd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            wait(NULL);
            close(p[1]);
            fd_in = p[0]; //save the input for the next command
            cmd++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @WilliamPursell yeah, that part didnt get copied! I added it

Comment: `dup2(fd_in, 0);` is probably not correct when `fd_in == 0`.  Maybe it's a no-op, but I suspect not.  The first thing `dup2` does is close the fd in the second argument.  Oops.  Try `if( fd_in != 0 ) { dup2(fd_in, 0); }`

Comment: @WilliamPursell What I posted works correctly. I tried your modification but it simply executes the first command `echo "test"` and exists correctly. There is no piping. Am I missing something?

My concern is to execute from with arguments passed in *argv[]

Comment: @WilliamPursell at least on Linux, “If <...> newfd has the same value as oldfd, then dup2() does nothing”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did all the multiprocessing part. You only need to do some array shuffling, to convert array of strings to array of arrays of strings.

If you don’t mind iterating the array two times, you can do like the following:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // count the commas
    int n = 0;
    for (int k = 1; k < argc; k++) {
        if (strcmp(argv[k], ",") == 0)
            n++;
    }
    int stage_count = n + 1;

    // allocate the pipeline stage list
    char ***cmd = calloc(stage_count + 1, sizeof(char**));

    // fill arguments for each stage
    int stage = 0;
    int first_arg = 1; // index of the first argument of current stage
    for (int k = 1; k <= argc; k++) {
        // stage arguments are terminated by a comma,
        // except of the last, where k == argc
        if ((k == argc) || (strcmp(argv[k], ",") == 0)) {
            // now, k is one greater than the index of the last argument of that stage
            int arg_count = k - first_arg;

            // save arguments for one pipeline stage
            // (note that only char pointers are copied, not the data they point to)
            // (also, you can use `malloc` but don’t forget to write terminating NULL then)
            char **args = calloc(arg_count + 1, sizeof(char*));
            memcpy(args, argv + first_arg, arg_count * sizeof(char*));
            cmd[stage] = args;

            stage++;
            first_arg = k + 1; // k refers to the delimiter so the next stage arguments start at k+1
        }
    }

    loop_pipe(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

You can refine this using special properties of `argv`, e.g. that `argv[argc] == NULL`, or that `argv`, as well as the argument strings themselves, is actually *writable*.

Comment: Much appreciated. One last thing, Im trying to get the status of the child and the parent, if lets say only fail "test" is executed as a command. But for some reason the return status Im getting is 1, when Im expecting a 127(commound not found). Ive made sure the descriptor isnt changed. I guess everything is flushed so I should just do _exit(127);

Comment: “Command not found” would be returned by the shell, but you don’t use one, calling the command directly with `execve`. And if that fails (e.g. if the command was not found) call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` no matter what the error was (`EXIT_FAILURE` is likely 1)